# Using PHP and C++ for data exchange?

Tags: php, c++

Is it possible to send data from C++ to PHP? I have wrote a server in C++ that connects to a database, and I was wondering if it is possible at all to use the socket library built into PHP to connect to the socket server written in C++. Would it just be PHP itself? I mean, would I not use JavaScript (AJAX) to call a PHP script that might do the socket work?

Basically, how do Google do this? I know some of their applications use C++/Java as their back-end, but is there any performance at all?

For those wondering why I am asking this question, then the answer is I don't want to rely on PHP to handle data as I am writing a game. I would like PHP to handle the web part, but not necessarily the game client so-to-speak; and I just think C++ would be a lot efficient at sending and receiving data to store in the database.

Has anyone done something like this and if so did you run into problems; and is this a practical solution at all?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you want two back-end appications. One for running the game, another, for running a website where people can see their game stats. Am I right?

Comment: Seems to me that if you can get C++ to interface with MySQL, you should be able to handle both your PHP and C++ code seperately. But then, I've never done this sort of thing. Anyone care to weigh in on this?

Answer (score 0):

Google use [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) for  data exchange between different services. Facebook has Thrift. Etc, etc. There's a plenty of protocols and libraries for you to choose from, but I'm afraid you'll have to do the research yourself.

Last time we had such a task (connecting C++ backends with PHP frontend), we wrote our own, very simple protocol. It's not that hard, in fact, it might be easier than implementing some abstraction on both sides.